# Android - setting the color of the action-bar overflow menu icon (3 dots)

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the color of the action-bar overflow menu icon (3 vertical dots).

Doing some research, I found out the following does it.

```
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

But the problem is that it changes color of some other UI that I'd rather not set.

Is there a way to set the color for just this icon.

Comment: can you share your style xml file

Comment: you can create your own custom actionbar.